# Laravel: global scope not loaded with relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I have some Laravel models (working with Laravel 5.8). User which has many Transaction which has many Repayment.

I want to load an User with all transactions and transactions.repayments. I know how to use the "with" Eloquent method to do so. Therefore, in order to retrieve an user with specific id and with the "transactions" and "transactions.repayments" relationships, I do something like this:

```php
$user = User::with(['transactions', 'transactions.repayments'])
        ->where('id', '=', <some_id>)
        ->first();
```

Within Repayment, I have added a global scope. Now, this is not loaded within the relationships. Does someone know why, please?

**EDIT:**
After comments from @Ersoy, I think it could be better if I post here something related to the actual code, so that it is possible to better understand the problem.

**Repayment**

```php
class Repayment extends BaseModel
{
    protected $appends = ['status_id'];

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new RepaymentStatusScope());
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function getStatusIdAttribute()
    {
        return array_key_exists('status_id', $this->attributes) ? $this->attributes['status_id'] : null;
    }
}
```

**RepaymentStatusScope**

```php
class RepaymentStatus implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
            $builder
                ->leftJoin(
                    DB::raw('(SELECT transaction_status_id as last_transaction_status, repayment_id
                        FROM repayment_transactions
                    ) AS __rt__last_transaction_status'),
                    function ($join) {
                        $join->on("repayments.last_repayment_transaction_id", '=', '__rt__last_transaction_status.repayment_id');
                    }
                );

            $statement = "IF(
                    repayments.rejected = 1, 1, IF(
                        repayments.completed = 0 OR __rt__total_paid_amounts.total_paid_amount > repayments.amount, IF(
                            repayments.last_repayment_transaction_id IS NULL, 2, IF(
                                __rt__total_paid_amounts.total_paid_amount <= repayments.amount AND __rt__total_paid_amounts.total_paid_amount > 0, 3, __rt__last_transaction_status.last_transaction_status)
                        ), 4
                    )
                ) AS status_id";

        $builder->selectRaw($statement);
    }
}
```

Comment: no need for `query()` and `get()` if you are going to fetch the first matching user. I reproduced/checked on my local env and it works (scopes are appended to the query). Please install clockwork/debugbar to see what queries are executed behind the scenes.

Comment: @Ersoy may you show me a gist of your code? I have added the global scope by  RepaymentScope class, not by a callback. I cannot find clockwork/debugbar on packagist.org

Comment: https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork it has instructions to install and how to use as well.

Comment: by saying "appended" i mean automatically appended - i didn't add manually by using callbacks/closures

Comment: @Ersoy I have updated the description with some code in order to show how I am implementing the codepaths. More clues about the possible problem, please?

Comment: The way i tested was simple scope with a single where condition (status = 1) - i am not sure about do raw subqueries inside the join can append global scopes.

Comment: @Ersoy you tested something with a really existing database column. I am writing about global scope with computed column. It works if I try to retrieve repayments, or transactions with repayments. It doesn't work when trying to get user with transactions with repayments

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it by myself. The matter was related to a wrongly built SQL instruction.